# Python, Change variable type

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a string variable, let's say name = 'Mark', and I want to change the variable's type which is currently string to a type that is imported with a module. The type is
<class 'discord.channel.TextChannel'>
I have tried to use the following code already, but it gave me the error you see below.
CODE:

```
name_converted = discord.channel.TextChannel('Mark')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 161, in on_message
    msgch = discord.channel.TextChannel('mark')
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: It really is not clear what you want to do. The source for that class is at [https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/757cfad38f340f31f1b18bc198b3aa83e9cbe6dc/discord/channel.py#L62`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/757cfad38f340f31f1b18bc198b3aa83e9cbe6dc/discord/channel.py#L62)

Comment: You don't create these classes manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you are trying to retrieve a channel from his name. Unfortunately **that is not possible** as multiple channel can have the same name. You will need to get the channel id and then you will be able to do the following :

```
chan_id = 0000 # This is the id of the channel.
msgch = await bot.fetch_channel(chan_id)
```

Comment: get_channel is not a coroutine, it shouldn’t be awaited

Comment: I meant to write fetch_channel, my fault

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'client' referenced before assignment

I changed bot to client because I use client instead of bot


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

Comment: I made a mistake, please find the updated code. And the error you have is because your client variable isn't defined, please ensure that you put the correct variable name in place of "bot"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use the [TextChannelConverter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=textchannelconverter#discord.ext.commands.TextChannelConverter). The following is an example **command** that works:

```py
@bot.command()
async def convert_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
  ...
```

The `: discord.TextChannel` tells discord.py to take the input (channel id, channel name, channel mention) and convert it to a TextChannel. What really happens in the background is this:

```py
user_input = ...  # user input from the command
channel_object = await command.TextChannelConverter.convert(ctx, user_input)
```

This isn't easy to use outside of a command, since it requires the `ctx` object. If this is used inside the `on_message` event, then you can do this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
  channel = await commands.TextChannelConverter.convert(ctx, message.content)
```

Otherwise, you'll have to customize the source code of `convert` to not require the context object. You can find it [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/6a52eea6ff75cf790a3e4d07c49ab3267df4b9e1/discord/ext/commands/converter.py#L333)